# How to assign a Composite task to an AD group in Visual Studio 2013 for a SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: active-directory, task, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation-4

So I am just starting out, and it's super insanely frustrating that there are NO answers out there that do anything other than assume I already have an intimate knowledge of this product.

I just want to assign a composite task to an AD group. Please, someone tell me how.